# Update doesn't work in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure to update a column(`LiveStatus`) to 'N' before inserting a new row of data and setting its column(`LiveStatus`) to 'Y' if the `DeviceID` of the new values is already there and its LiveSTatus is 'Y'.

It inserts the new values but the `livestatus` of the previous row with the same `DeviceID`is still 'Y'.

The stored procedure:

```
    DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`testmysql`@`%` PROCEDURE `PDADeviceAssign`(

IN DeviceID varchar(50),
IN EmpID varchar(50),
IN PlazaID varchar(50),
IN LaneID varchar(50),
IN AssignDateTime varchar(50),
IN AssignTranID varchar(50),
IN AssignedBy varchar(50),
IN Start_at varchar(50),
IN End_at varchar(50),
IN IsNextDay varchar(50),
IN ClientID varchar(50),
IN Description varchar(50)
)
BEGIN

    declare Sno int; 

    set Sno=(SELECT MAX(Sno) FROM posassignment WHERE DeviceID=DeviceID);    
    update posassignment set LiveStatus ='N' where Sno=Sno;

Insert into posassignment(DeviceID,EmpId,PlazaID,LaneID,AssignDateTime,AssignTranID,AssignedBy,LiveStatus,Start_at,End_at,IsNextDay,ClientId,Description)
   values (DeviceID,EmpID,PlazaID,LaneID,AssignDateTime,AssignTranID,AssignedBy,'Y',Start_at,End_at,IsNextDay,ClientId,Description); 
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your code:

```
declare Sno int; 

set Sno=(SELECT MAX(Sno) FROM posassignment WHERE DeviceID=DeviceID);    
update posassignment set LiveStatus ='N' where Sno=Sno;
```

The `update` is equivalent to:

```
update posassignment set LiveStatus = 'N' where Sno is not null;
```

That is, neither `sno` reference is to the parameter.  You have the same problem with `DeviceID`:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`testmysql`@`%` PROCEDURE `PDADeviceAssign`(
    IN in_DeviceID varchar(50),
    IN in_EmpID varchar(50),
    . . .
)
BEGIN
    declare v_Sno int; 

    set v_Sno = (SELECT MAX(Sno)
                 FROM posassignment
                 WHERE DeviceID = in_DeviceID
                );  

    update posassignment
        set LiveStatus = 'N'
        where Sno = v_Sno;
```